# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\User::map()

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I want to add additional data to `$user` collection so can get the profile fields in the `view`

I have tried using `$user['profileFields'] = $this->getProfileFields()` and pass `$user` to the view using `compatct` or `with` and this is working fine.

### DD

[image]

However, I have found some reference over the net saying I can extend using `map` but when I tried it is giving the following error

> **BadMethodCallException**
>   Call to undefined method App\User::map()

So here is what I am trying to understand

> **Question:**
>   Is the below code is wrong and won't work for what I am looking for and the first approach is the solution? Is there any
>   recommended method to add additional data to the `$user` collection?

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    $user->map(function ($user){
       $user['profileFields'] = $this->getProfileFields();
       return $user;
    });

    return view('admin.user.show', compact('user'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collection methods are works on the collection, here you're getting the object of user.

```
$user->profileFields = $user->getProfileFields();
return view('admin.user.show', compact('user'));
```

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If the `profileFields` is in another table and having a `foreign key` with model `ProfileField`, then try to add a [one to one relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) to the `User` model.

Inside the `User` model, add a function

```
public function profileFields()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ProfileField', 'foreign_key','other_key');
}
```

This will give you the `profileFields` in every user when calling using eloquent.

Comment: Thanks, Rijosh, it is not for the relational table but just to get an array of pre-defined fields from the language.